# express-jwt - typeError: done is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I'm using express-jwt to control the user privileges of my startup project, but I'm getting an error when I try to request access (using Postman) an api that only the admin can access.
This is my authJwt document:

```
import { expressjwt } from "express-jwt";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';


dotenv.config();
const secretJwt = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

function authJwt() {
    return expressjwt({
        secret: secretJwt, 
        algorithms: ['HS256'], //https://jwt.io/
        isRevoked: isRevoked 
    })
    .unless({ 
        path: 
        [
            '/users/login',
            '/users/register',        
            { 
                url: /\/categories(.*)/, // (https://regex101.com/)
                methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] 
            }
        ]
    })
}

async function isRevoked(req, payload, done) {
    if(!payload.isAdmin) {
        done(null, true)
    }
   done(); 
}

export default authJwt;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: done is not a function<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.isRevoked (file:///C:/Users/OneDrive%20-%20GfK/Documents/IPCA/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20Web/PWeb%20-%20Projecto/FTA%20/backend/middlewares/jwt.js:42:9)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\\OneDrive - GfK\Documents\IPCA\Programação Web\PWeb - Projecto\FTA\backend\node_modules\express-jwt\dist\index.js:157:54<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at step (C:\Users\rui.lopes\OneDrive - GfK\Documents\IPCA\Programação Web\PWeb - Projecto\FTA\backend\node_modules\express-jwt\dist\index.js:56:23)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.next (C:\Users\rui.lopes\OneDrive - GfK\Documents\IPCA\Programação Web\PWeb - Projecto\FTA\backend\node_modules\express-jwt\dist\index.js:37:53)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at fulfilled (C:\Users\rui.lopes\OneDrive - GfK\Documents\IPCA\Programação Web\PWeb - Projecto\FTA\backend\node_modules\express-jwt\dist\index.js:28:58)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) in the "Migration from v6" - Looks like there was a change to the structure of isRevoked - `The isRevoked function had (req, payload, cb), now it can return a promise and receives (req, token)`

Answer (score 2):

As per updates:
The isRevoked function had (req, payload, cb), now it can return a promise and receives (req, token). token has header and payload.

IsRevoked = (req: express.Request, token: jwt.Jwt | undefined) => Promise<boolean`>

this worked for me:

```
async function isRevoked(req, token){
    if(!token.payload.isAdmin) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I find this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

const {expressjwt: expressJwt}  = require('express-jwt')

exports.authJwt = expressJwt ({
secret: secretJwt,
algorithms: ['HS256'], //https://jwt.io/
isRevoked: isRevoked
})....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
async function isRevoked(req, token) {
    if (!token.payload.isAdmin) {
        console.log(token.payload.isAdmin)
        return true
    }
    console.log(token.payload.isAdmin)
    
}
```

this work for me